# shell prompt did not show directory

Tags: bash, shell

i am using /bin/bash as a shell. But my prompt did not show the current directory. It shows only

```
-bash-4.2$
```

I have created a file in ~/.bashrc where i add:

```
export PS1='$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)$ '
```

If i log out and login again the prompt is still the same.

How can i change the prompt to display user and current directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~/.bashrc is not run when Bash is invoked as a "login" shell. For this to work, you need to add a

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

to your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile script (which is the "login shell" equivalent of bashrc).

---

`PS1` does not need to be exported to the environment (since it's used by the shell itself, not by commands you run from it). The same prompt style can be achieved more efficiently by using shell variables or even bash PS1-specific expansions:

```
PS1='$USER@$HOSTNAME:$PWD\$ '
PS1='\u@\h:$PWD\$ '    # doesn't collapse $HOME
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '      # collapses $HOME into ~
```

Comment: There is no ~/.profile script. How can i check where to find it?

Comment: You find it exactly at ~/.profile (or at ~/.bash_profile) – the location does not vary between systems. If it's not there, create one.

Comment: Thanks ~/.profile worked!